# Form with multiple values in array from a file

Tags: php, arrays, forms, simple-html-dom

I have a CSV file with 1 column and 1 code per row. For each code I have to create an URL and extract HTML informations from that URL:

```
    $lines = file('sku.csv');
    echo '<FORM method="post" action="process.php">';

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="'.$line.'" name="search-field" id="header-search-field">';
    }
    echo '<button type="submit">Search</button></FORM>';
```

and the **process.php**:

```
require ("simple_html_dom.php");

foreach($_POST as $var){
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com/$var.html");
    $result = $html->find('table[id=item_specification]');
    echo $result[0];

}
```

Codes are just like this:

B0302773 
B0323322 
B0344576 
B0360996

The main problem is that it shows only the last code result (in this case B0360996) and not for everyone, and when the **table[id=item_specification]** is **not found**, it hangs. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the HTML array format for your input name:

```
name="search-field[]"
```

Otherwise all you are doing is submitting a form with many inputs each with the same name, so only the last one will be recognized.

This will definitely resolve your first problem. As for the hanging issue you will need to debug with in your logs or open a separate question about **file_get_html** functionality.

**EDIT**

In your processing script you can then iterate over the specific field array, rather than the entire POST array which may also hold unwanted fields :

```
foreach($_POST['search-field'] as $var){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the form in loop which is wrong. It should be like this.

```
$lines = file('sku.csv');
echo '<FORM method="post" action="process.php">';

foreach ($lines as $line) {
echo '<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="'.$line.'" name="search-field" id="header-search-field">';
}
echo '<button type="submit">Search</button></FORM>';
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't close the form in loop, just an error while pasting the code. I'm going to modify my question.